# NoClassDefFoundError while using Simple Logging Facade for Java, even with slf4j-api.jar

Tags: java, database, connection, slf4j

The SLF4J documentation states that in the event of a NoClassDefFoundError, the slf4j-api-1.7.25 jar file should be added to the classpath. I have added this file to my classpath, but I still receive this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFac
        at SchemaDetailsTest.<clinit>(SchemaDetailsTest.java:9)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 1 more
```

Here is my classpath:

```
java -cp "C:\Users\Tiffany\Desktop\baffle-sql-parser-master\library\src\demos\analyzescript\slf4j-1.7.25.jar;C:\Users\Tiffany\Desktop\baffle-sql-parser-master\library\src\demos\analyzescript\slf4j-1.7.25\slf4j-api-1.7.25-sources.jar;C:\Users\Tiffany\Desktop\baffle-sql-parser-master\library\src\demos\analyzescript\slf4j-1.7.25\slf4j-simple-1.7.25.jar;C:\Users\Tiffany\Desktop\baffle-sql-parser-master\library\src\demos\analyzescript\mysql-connector-java-5.1.42-bin.jar;C:\Users\Tiffany\Desktop\baffle-sql-parser-master\library\src\demos\analyzescript" SchemaDetailsTest
```

And here is some of the code:

```
 private static Logger log = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(SchemaDetailsTest.class);
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        String databaseName = "myDbName";
        String JDBC_DRIVER = "jdbc:mysql://34.210.136.158:3306/";
        String USER = "servicenowapp";
        String PWD = "test";
        // Setup the connection with the DB
       Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(JDBC_DRIVER, USER, PWD);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

`slf4j-api-1.7.25-sources.jar` is the Java source, you want the binary file. Change it to `slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar`

You might also simplify your classpath a bit (and if you configure it as an environment variable, you'll find it easier to maintain)

```
set "SLF4J_VER=1.7.25"
set "MYSQL_VER=5.1.42"
set "DESKTOP=C:\Users\Tiffany\Desktop"
set "SCRIPT_LIB=%DESKTOP\baffle-sql-parser-master\library\src\demos\analyzescript"
set "SLF4J_LIB=%SCRIPT_LIB%\slf4j-%SLF4J_VER%"
set "CLASSPATH=%SLF4J_LIB%\slf4j-api-%SLF4J_VER%.jar;%SLF4J_LIB%\slf4j-simple-%SLF4J_VER%.jar;%SCRIPT_LIB%\mysql-connector-java-%MYSQL_VER%-bin.jar;%SCRIPT_LIB%"
java SchemaDetailsTest
```

Comment: Or better yet, use Maven or Gradle.

Comment: @chrylis Or apache-ivy or sbt.

Answer (score 0):

The error is you add a wrong **source** jar `slf4j-api-1.7.25-sources.jar`, you must add the **bin** jar something like `slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar`